# How to get calling line number and file name

Tags: c++, visual-studio, logging, c++17, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to log memory allocation. I want to be able to specify exactly which function call (line number and file name) called a particular function at runtime. Something like:

```
// overloading operator new
void* operator new [](std::size_t const count) {
  void* p = std::malloc(count);
  if (!p) throw std::bad_alloc{};
  std::cout << "Allocated " << count << " bytes in file '"
            << CALLING_FUNCTION_FILE_NAME << "'. Line "
            << CALLING_FUNCTION_LINE_NUMBER << '.\n';
  return p;
}
```

So that later on when I call it like:

```
// File sourceFileFoo.cpp

void foo() {               // line 41
    int* ip = new int[10]; // line 42
    delete[] ip;           // line 43
}                          // line 44
```

The output should be something like:

```
Allocated 40 bytes in file 'sourceFileFoo.cpp'. Line 42.
```

`CALLING_FUNCTION_FILE_NAME` expanded to the name of the file in which `operator new` was called (`sourceFileFoo.cpp`) and `CALLING_FUNCTION_LINE_NUMBER` expanded to the line in which `operator new` was called (42).

1. I know this is going to be implementation specific if at all possible. I am working with Visual Studio and C++17.
2. I cannot do something like define a macro `NEW` which does logging and then does allocation.

Comment: Which C++ version are you using?

Comment: [boost.stacktrace](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/stacktrace.html) might be worth a look.  Although from what I recall the 'quality' of the information provided can be highly dependent on platform/compilation flags etc.

Comment: @NutCracker C++17. Edited the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment [boost.stacktrace](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/stacktrace.html) is probably what you're looking for.  So, simplictically, your code would look something like...

```
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

/*
 * overloading operator new
 */
void *operator new [](std::size_t const count)
{
  void *p = std::malloc(count);
  if (!p)
    throw std::bad_alloc{};
  std::cout << "Allocated " << count << " bytes at "
            << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace() << '.\n';
  return p;
}
```